I can't understand tha "Singleton pattern violates DIP."
I learned that In singleton pattern,  the client depends on the concrete class in the dependency relationship.
So singleton pattern violates DIP.
And in the lecture i'm listening (it's spring(java) lecture), teacher showed this code
public class SingletonService {

    private static final SingletonService instance = new SingletonService();
    
    //method that brings instant
    public static SingletonService getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    
    // prevent constructor
    private SingletonService() {
    }
}

and I understood this code.
Teacher told "because it uses getInstance() method, it depends on the concrete class"
but I can't understand this.
somebody help me
I'm no expecting something, I just wanna know why singleton violates DIP.
And I tried some example singleton codes, but still I don't know why singleton makes the client depends on the concrete class in the dependency relationship.

Define your term “DIP”.

The Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP) promotes writing code that relies on abstractions (general concepts) rather than specific implementations (concrete classes). This makes code more flexible and easier to maintain.
Consider the following example using the Singleton pattern:
public class Client {
    public void doSomething() {
        SingletonService service = SingletonService.getInstance();
        service.performAction();
    }
}

In this example, the Client class is tightly coupled to the SingletonService class, violating the DIP. The DIP suggests that the code should instead depend on abstractions:
public class Client {
    private final SomeInterfaceService service;

    public Client(SomeInterfaceService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        service.performAction();
    }
}

In this case, the Client class depends on the SomeInterfaceService interface, not the concrete SingletonService class. This kind of looser coupling is beneficial in several ways.
For example, if you want to use different implementations of SomeInterfaceService, you can achieve this easily without modifying the Client class:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeInterfaceService serviceA = new ServiceA();
        Client client = new Client(serviceA);
        client.doSomething();
    }
}

If you change serviceA to serviceB, you do not need to modify the Client class:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeInterfaceService serviceB = new ServiceB();
        Client client = new Client(serviceB);
        client.doSomething();
    }
}

By adhering to the Dependency Inversion Principle, you achieve:

Loose Coupling: The Client class depends on abstractions rather than concrete implementations, making the code more flexible and maintainable.
Improved Testability: You can easily mock SomeInterfaceService in unit tests.
Flexibility: You can switch between different implementations of SomeInterfaceService without changing the client code.


so your opinion is in the singletonService Class, the class instance is already made, so client has to use that instant without chance to choose.
And that breaks abstraction & DIP right?

@김유담, yes. singletonService is concrete implementation but not abstraction.

Couple of things to notice here:

What is DIP? Dependency Inversion Principle. Dependency Inversion is the
strategy of depending upon interfaces or abstract functions and classes
rather than upon concrete functions and classes.
How is DIP achieved? Use of abstraction(interfaces) and
implementation(concrete classes)
Why to use DIP ? To achieve loose-coupling within the code and reusability
of code.
Now coming to your question, How singleton pattern violates DIP?

In singleton pattern what we do is use a static concrete method of the concrete class to get the instance of that class which makes it tightly coupled as each time I want to change the implementation of that concrete class I must have to touch the code of that concrete class, according to the DIP instead of this singleton should be an interface and I should only implement another concrete class to that and it should change the logic. This is how it. In frameworks like Spring this has been partially solved according to me, pardon me if I say this statement wrong.
In Springboot
@Service
public interface SingletonService{
  //abstraction code goes here
}

public class SingletonServiceMySqlImpl{
  // implementation goes here
}

//In configuration 
@Bean
@Scope("singleton") //to define singleton behavior
SingletonService getSingleTonService(){
 return new SingletonServiceMySqlImpl();
}

//and whenever you need to use this
@Autowired
private SingletonService singletonService;


Yes, you are correct. In the Singleton design pattern, the client depends on the concrete class, which can violate the Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP). Let's break down why this is the case and explore potential solutions.
Understanding the Issue
Singleton Pattern and DIP
⦿ Singleton Pattern: Ensures a class has only one instance and provides a global point of access to it.
⦿ Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP): High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions. Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions.
In the Singleton pattern, you typically access the single instance via a static method, which directly couples the client code to the concrete class. This direct dependency on the concrete class means the client cannot easily be changed to use a different implementation without modifying the client code itself, thus violating DIP. to understand it in detail have look on this article
